# thawing and cooking frozen raw chicken backs

Tags: chicken, raw

I purchased a case of raw chicken back bones. Cleaned, portioned into 4 lb sealed bags and frozen.  I bought them to make batches of bone broth.  When I unthaw a bag in my refrigerator I notice a lot of blood. Is it safe to put all of that blood/juice and bone parts - covered with water into my crock pot to cook up slow for 12 hours?